# error with ascii encryption program in python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm a few weeks into coding and have an assignment to do that needs to encrypt text input into ascii, or decrypt the message. I cant use two codes to encrypt and decrypt, this can be done by entering the negative version of the passkey ( hence the functions) I got the encryption working on its own but am having difficulty getting this to work as a package. The program need to take an option from user (encrypt or decrypt, then use the values returned from text and key to convert the text in the main function. 
Ive been at this for 10 hours with lots of researching and changing elements, but seem to keep falling down. Any advice offered would be awesome. The error when running I have put under the code.

```
def main(function, message, passkey):
    #takes value of mode and applies text. then uses key to encrypt or decrypt
    encrypt = ""
    for x in message:
    if x == " ":
        encrypt += " "
    else:
        encrypt += chr((((ord(x) - 65) + passkey % 26) + 65))


def mode():
    # determines either encryption or decryption. 
    func = input("Which mode would you like? E for encryption or D for decryption.\n").upper()
    if func[0] =='E': return 'E'
    elif func[0] == 'D': return 'D'
    else: print("Not a valid option. Please try again")

def text():
    #depending on value of mode, either input a sentance to encrypt or an ecrypted message to decode.
    if function == 'E':
        sentance = input("Please enter a sentance to encrypt.\n").upper()
        if all(x.isalpha or x.isspace() for x in sentance):
            return text
        else: sentance = input("Only uppercase alpha characters and spaces allowed. Try again.\n")
    else:
        return input("Enter coded message for decrypting:\n")


def key():
    #depending on value of mode, enter positve key to encrypt or same key in negative form to decrypt.
    if function == 'E':
        return abs(int(input("Enter passkey: ")))
    elif function == 'D':
        return -abs(int(input("Enter passkey: ")))

function = mode()
message = text()
passkey = key()

    print (message)
    print(main(function, message, passkey))
```

"""
when run:
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > RESTART:ex6 test.py =
> > >       Which mode would you like? E for encryption or D for decryption.
> > >       e
> > >       Please enter a sentence to encrypt.
> > >       hello world
> > >       Enter passkey: 4
> > >       
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\ninja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\ex6 test.py", line 43, in 
> > >           print(main(function, message, passkey))
> > >         File "C:\Users\ninja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\ex6 test.py", line 6, in main
> > >           for x in message:
> > >       TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
> > >
> > > """

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error message it says that a `'function' object is not iterable`. That is because you are returning `text` which is a function.

To fix this, simply change the return statement in line 28 to return `sentance` instead. You will also want to return the encrypted message in `main`.

```
def main(function, message, passkey):
    # takes value of mode and applies text. then uses key to encrypt or decrypt
    encrypt = ""
    for x in message:
        if x == " ":
            encrypt += " "
        else:
            encrypt += chr((((ord(x) - 65) + passkey % 26) + 65))
    return encrypt


def mode():
    # determines either encryption or decryption.
    func = input("Which mode would you like? E for "
                 "encryption or D for decryption.\n").upper()
    if func[0] == 'E':
        return 'E'
    elif func[0] == 'D':
        return 'D'
    else:
        print("Not a valid option. Please try again")


def text():
    # depending on value of mode, either input a sentance
    # to encrypt or an ecrypted message to decode.
    if function == 'E':
        sentance = input("Please enter a sentance to encrypt.\n").upper()
        if all(x.isalpha or x.isspace() for x in sentance):
            return sentance
        else:
            sentance = input("Only uppercase alpha characters "
                             "and spaces allowed. Try again.\n")
    else:
        return input("Enter coded message for decrypting:\n")


def key():
    # depending on value of mode, enter positve key to encrypt
    # or same key in negative form to decrypt.
    if function == 'E':
        return abs(int(input("Enter passkey: ")))
    elif function == 'D':
        return -abs(int(input("Enter passkey: ")))


function = mode()
message = text()
passkey = key()

print(message)
print(main(function, message, passkey))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast advice. Correcting the return value took care of the error. It now outputs an encrypted text. Sort of. Now if i input a word (i.e hello), the program now only returns one letter ( in this case S). when I made that part before assigning to a function it outputted each letter as a encrypted version.

Comment: Are you sure that you copy this correctly? Because it works for me ("HELLO" becomes "LIPPS").

Comment: Weird.. I copied my code back and run it, and it works! Really grateful for the support thank you!